# Acronym won't pluralize correctly causing circular dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, circular-dependency

I would like to name my controller `ESCsController`, `ESC` being the acronym in question. I found the rails inflection docs which describe a way in which to accomplish this.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

> Note: Acronyms that are passed to pluralize will no longer be recognized, since the         acronym will not occur as a delimited unit in the pluralized result. To work around this, you must specify the pluralized form as an acronym as well:
>
> ```
> acronym 'API'
> camelize(pluralize('api')) #=> 'Apis'
>
> acronym 'APIs'
> camelize(pluralize('api')) #=> 'APIs'
> ```

I created my controller and models after adding this to `environment.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections { |i| 
   i.acronym 'ESC'
   i.acronym 'ESCs'
}
```

Tested in the console these work perfectly. `'ESC'.pluralize()` returns `ESCs` and `'ESCs'.singularize()` returns `ESC` as expected

Controllers and models were generated through `rails generate model ESC` and `rails generate controller ESCs` respectively. This created `escs_controller.rb` and the model `esc.rb` as expected.

In my routes.rb I used to have

```
resources :ESCs, path: '/parts/escs'
```

which returned this error: `'ESCs' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use`

I ended up changing it to:

```
resources :ESCs, controller: 'escs', path: '/parts/escs'
```

However, now whenever I try and visit a page I get a circular dependency error:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant EscsController
```

Anyone know what's going on? It looks like whatever is trying to load the controller isn't seeing that it should be `ESCsController` and not `EscsController`. I'm new to rails so this could be a simple problem...

I'm using Rails 4.0.2

Here's the relevant part of the full stack trace.

```
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:461:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in `get'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving code that adds the new inflections from `environment.rb` to `config/initializers/inflections.rb` then reload the server. Also, you don't need to specify a `controller` option for your route, just make it `resources :escs, path: '/parts/escs'` and it shall work fine.

Comment: This worked! At first I added it to the inflection file and it still didn't work, but after re-specifying the resource's controller:

`resources :ESCs, controller: 'escs', path: '/parts/escs'`

it worked! Unfortunately it looks like I still have to specify the controller or I get an error when starting up the rails server. Also, just `:esc` for the resource didn't work since that messed up some other rail magic I had going on (such as using `ESCs_path`). Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem :). Apparently I made a typo in the other part of the answer; I meant `resources :escs`, not `resources :esc`, sorry about that. I'm not sure why you would want to use uppercase letters for resource name, but that's likely a bad practice since identifiers that start with capital letter are considered constants in Ruby.

Comment: True. Well it's working now so there's no point in changing it. If I run in to any more problems down the line I'll probably just end up renaming everything to the downcased version. Thanks again.